# How do I build a combination tree in Python?

Tags: python, data-structures, tree

I have the following two classes for Node and Tree

Node:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, identifier):
        self._children = []
        self._identifier = identifier

    def add_children(self, node):
       self._children.append(node)

    def get_children(self):
       return self._children
```

Tree with levels:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self._levels = {}

    def add_levels(self, index, nodes):
        self._levels[index] = nodes

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        # further stuff
        return self._levels[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._levels)
```

I would like to build a combination tree as shown below. The identifier of each node is give n(for instance, 12, 13, 23 is known). How can I recursively build the tree so that each level of the tree will have a list of nodes?

[image: Tree List of Nodes]

Comment: must this need to be done "recursively"?

Comment: Not necessarily recursive.That's just my suggestion.

Comment: Cool, well I was able to "build" the tree, as in the answer below. Is there more that needs to be done?

Comment: The given answer is specific. I have a list of n elements, not exactly 3. Then I used itertools to generate the combination. Once I have the possible combinations of the list I will build a tree. My issue is when I try to build a tree from a combination of a list of 20 elements I have got bad performance. I was wondering maybe my implementation is not pythonic or good enough to build such a tree. Any suggestion?

Comment: Your implementation could possibly be improved but for just 20 elements I don't see how it would produce bad performance. Feel free to update your question with the scenario that produces the poor performance and I or maybe someone else can suggest improvements.